# Awkward DAO string manipulation issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, dao

I'm working with a legacy vb6 product and I've come across a problem whereby I need to get the filename part of a full path from a database table through DAO. I've got no access to VBA functions here so I'm looking specifically for MS Access SQL. I have no way of dropping some extra code after the query.  I **CAN'T** change/refactor the solution short of modifying the SQL.

Now, DAO doesn't have any `instrrev` or `replace` functionality so I'm pretty limited.

Any guesses out there? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the actual database . . .

The only thing I can think of (and I wracked by brains on this one, sorry mate) is to use repeated calls to instr, nested in iif statements e.g. to replace this call to inStrRev

```
SELECT IIf(InStr([FileName],""\"")>0,Mid$([Filename],InStrRev([Filename],""\"")+1),[Filename]) FROM Table1
```

You'd have a compeltely insane

```
SELECT IIf(InStr([FileName],""\"")>0,Mid$([Filename],iif(InStr(1, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(2, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(3, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(4, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(5, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(6, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(7, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(8, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, iif(InStr(9, [FileName], ""\"") > 0, 1, InStr(9, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(8, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(7, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(6, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(5, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(4, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(3, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(2, [FileName], ""\"")), InStr(1, [FileName], ""\""))),[Filename]) from table1
```

This will work for a path thats 10 or so sub folders deep.
If you think 10 sub folders is too little, I've a bit of vba to generate the statement to what ever depth you require.

```
Function BuildNestedIIfs(ByVal depth As Integer, byval maxDepth as integer) As String
    Dim locator As String
    If depth < maxDepth Then
        locator = "InStr(" & depth & ", [FileName], """"\"""")"
        Build = "iif(" & locator & " > 0, " & Build(depth + 1, maxDepth) & ", " & locator & ")"
    Else
       Build = "0"
    End If
End Function
```

It is obscene, but should work

Comment: lol.  Yeah, obscene is the word.  If i could give you more than 1+ i would just for having constitution to write that!  I had considered that as a solution but it's just nonsense.  It's all ended up being thrown back as a code change for a service pack release now so we don't need to do this kind of thing.  Good work though dude.

Comment: Thank feck for that! I've been in positions where an abomination like the above is the only solution or when a fix is needed for something RIGHT NOW. I'm glad those nested IIf's will never see light of day. Best of luck

Comment: @Binary Worrier: My first intuition also was to write a set of nested IIf()s and substitute InStrRev() with them. But I dismissed the idea for being so ugly and limited. +1 for the sheer effort on your part. :D

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the built-in vba functions like `instr`, `replace`, `mid`, etc.

There is a "sandbox" mode that may block them - see this on how to unblock them http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294698

Comment: Nice try but I'm running under NetworkService so i don't have permissions to the registry and this is a support issue so there's nothing i could do in InstallShield at this point.  Good call though.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do a lot of DAO programming, but that was 10-15 years ago...

Can you change the DAO to call an Access QueryDef and then fix it up there?

Comment: Sorry man, no dice.  I have the same problem using QueryDefs.  Nice try.

Comment: How is that possible?  It's been a while but I am certain that QueryDefs can use Access Basic functions.